# Vim hides lines that are too long to be displayed completely

Tags: vim, macvim

Editing a document where I didn't bother to make line breaks, I noticed that Vim (MacVim 8.0 to be precise), instead of just showing that part of the line that fits, *completely hides* lines of text that are too long to fit on the current screen. The space that would be occupied by the part of the line that does fit is simply left blank, as if the characters had become invisible.

Is there a way to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, setting `:set display=lastline` will help.

```
    Change the way text is displayed.  This is comma separated list of
    flags:
    lastline        When included, as much as possible of the last line
                    in a window will be displayed.  "@@@" is put in the 
                    last columns of the last screen line to indicate the 
                    rest of the line is not displayed.
    truncate        Like "lastline", but "@@@" is displayed in the first
                    column of the last screen line.  Overrules "lastline".
    uhex            Show unprintable characters hexadecimal as <xx>
                    instead of using ^C and ~C. 

    When neither "lastline" nor "truncate" is included, a last line that
    doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.
```

You can also try `:set nowrap`.

Comment: Thanks, `set display=lastline` solved it (`set display=truncate` is acceptable too)! I find it weird that `lastline` or `truncate` aren't the default.